# Access Denied for uploading images to AWS S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am trying to upload images to my S3 Bucket. But I am receiving "AccessDenied: Access Denied at Request.extractError" error. The Dev NodeJS server is running in an EC2 Instance. Surprisingly, upload image functionality is working when I am running the server in localhost. Same credentials are being used in the local server and the dev server. And the IAM user has both administrator and AmazonS3FullAccess permissions.The S3 Bucket doesnt have any policy and the objects within the bucket can be public.

This is my NodeJS code for uploading an image.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION
});
const S3 = new AWS.S3();

uploadImage: async (title, file, mime) => {
    return await S3.upload({
        Bucket: process.env.AWS_S3_IMAGES,
        Key: title,
        Body: file,
        ACL: "public-read",
        ContentType: mime
    }).promise()
},
```

This is the error that I am receiving.

```
AccessDenied: Access Denied\n    at Request.extractError (/home/ec2-user/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:700:35)\n    at Request.callListeners(/home/ec2-user/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)\n    at Request.emit (/home/ec2-user/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)\n    at Request.emit (/home/ec2-user/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)\n    at Request.transition (/home/ec2-user/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)\n    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/home/ec2-user/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)\n    at /home/ec2-user/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10\n    at Request. <anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)\n    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)\n    at Request.callListeners (/home/ec2-user/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)\n    at Request.emit (/home/ec2-user/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)\n    at Request.emit (/home/ec2-user/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)\n    at Request.transition (/home/ec2-user/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)\n    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/home/ec2-user/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)\n    at /home/ec2-user/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10\n    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)\n    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)\n    at Request.callListeners (/home/ec2-user/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)\n    at callNextListener (/home/ec2-user/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:96:12)\n    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/home/ec2-user/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:313:13)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:387:35)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (domain.js:470:12)
```

I have been trying to solve this issue for the last few days But couldnt find any leads. It will be great if any one of you can point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would check that the bucket name in `process.env.AWS_S3_IMAGES` is actually what you expected. Also, double-check the credentials via STS GetCallerIdentity, re-check the Block Public Access settings, and check any explicit deny statements 
 in the bucket policy.

Comment: Thanks for the response @jarmod. I kept logs within the function. The values of the environment variables(access key, secret key and region) are same both in the local and dev server. The credentials are the same. And regarding the bucket policy, I checked in the permissions tab of the bucket, the policy field is empty. I couldn't find any setting that is restricting access to the EC2 Instance. Let me know If there is anything specific that I need to check.

Comment: The AWS_S3_IMAGES variable also has the correct value And the Block Public Access Settings is turned off.

Comment: If you have region and creds in those AWS_xxxx environment variables, you shouldn't have to explicitly configure any of them (they'll be retrieved by the environment credentials provider). Just remove your entire AWS.config.update() call and re-test

Comment: At this point, I don't think the issue is how you're providing credentials to the SDK. Can you issue other calls, such as `S3.listObjectsV2({Bucket: someotherbucket, MaxKeys:10})` and successfully log the resulting data?

Answer (score -1):

Apply below policies in s3 console > Bucket policy editor of 'Permissions'.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "editor",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<IAM-user-ID>:user/testuser"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:Put*",
                "s3:Delete*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "editor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```